# how to store data on a "secure" place so that nobody can access to it

Tags: 12.04, encryption, ecryptfs, luks, kiosk

I am building a "Kiosk-Computer"-Terminal for my client.

At the moment the "Kiosk-Mode" is accessing into Ubuntu with the guest-user, this is enough for my costumer at the moment. ( btw. if somebody know a good opensource kiosk lockdown software, please tell me. )

But one questions is unclear, what if somebody take the harddisk out, or, take the whole computer and then accessing with another computer to the harddisk, the answer is, the thief will have access to the data. I would preffeer to enrypct the data but there are some limitations. When i encrypt the whole harddisk, every startup of the computer need the harddisk passphrase. Is there a way to encrypt my whole disk without entering on every boot the passphrase? Or can i encrypt selected files, the maingoal is that these files which i would encrypt are config-files for sensitive software which should run on the guest user...hope you understand me..

best regards

Comment: Kiosks shouldn't store any data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to encrypt your hard drive – or any of the files on it, for that matter – you have to be prepared to enter a password at least once per boot. That's the price to pay.

Sorry if this sounds harsh, but it's just the way it is. In order to encrypt something, you have to have a password you enter every time. Without it, e.g. with the complete key lying somewhere on your hard disk, the encryption would be useless since anybody could decrypt your files.